# Laravel Query result page 1 is correct but page 2 is not correct because page 2 show record other than desire record

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

First query show demanded record but when I click page2 it show all record not query demanded record. My lawyer table is

[image]

route:
Route::get('Search','solicitorClient@search')->name('search');

```
$search=DB::table('lawyer')
                ->where([
                    ['specialization','LIKE', '%'.$request->expertise.'%'],
                    ['location','LIKE','%'.$request->city.'%'],
                    ['zip_code','LIKE','%'.$request->zip_code.'%']
                ])->orderBy('payment_price','desc')
                ->paginate(3);
```

I desired to show only lawyer record which is specialization in 'copyright'
but i click page2 its show all record other than 'copyright' specialization
page 1 url:
http://localhost/solicitor/public/Search?expertise=Copyright&city=&zip_code=
when i click on page 2 its url change to
http://localhost/solicitor/public/Search?page=2

[my query page 2 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjlOP.png)

Comment: Please see how to create an [mcve].  As-is, we don't have nearly enough information about your code in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your URLs in both pages again. I think it happens because you are getting `expertise` parameter from your URL and it doesn't appear on your page 2.

try this on your view:

```
{{ $search->appends(['expertise' => $expertise])->links() }}
```

And in your controller:

```
$expertise = $request->expertise;
return view('search.view', compact('search', 'expertise'));
```

Comment: its correct its url changing issue but this is not correct answer because client choose  expertise dynamically its changing every time

Comment: your welcome. if it was helpful please accept it as the answer.